# Operadores logicos indicando uma faixa entre numeros

Tags: javascript, operadores

é uma duvidas simples: como especificar uma faixa de numeros utilizando operadores
logicos? por exemplo: se o numero digitado estiver entre 1 e dez,notificar que é muito pouco?
essa sintaxe é valida?

```
if(valor>1&&9){alert("muito pouco")}
if else{valor>10&&15 alert("bom!")}
if else{ valor>15&&20 alert("muito bom!")}
```

Comment: Isso é JavaScript? Enfim, se for pra testar se o número está entre 1 e 10, seria `if (valor >= 1 && valor <= 10) { alert("muito pouco") }` - já para ter várias condições encadeadas, é `else if` e não `if else`, algo assim: https://ideone.com/tl0gye  - não querendo parecer chato nem nada, mas como parece que vc está "apanhando" da sintaxe básica da linguagem, sugiro voltar para o básico e começar [daqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript#tutorials) - sério, não é ironia nem nada, é uma tentativa genuína de ajudar...

Comment: sim, estou apanhando pq comecei faz pouco tempo ahaha.. obrigado pela ajuda! ^^

Answer (score 2):

Respondendo a sua pergunta, não a sintaxe que usou não é válida os [Operadores Lógicos Binários](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#operadores_l%C3%B3gicos_bin%C3%A1rios) são normalmente usados com valores booleanos e retornam um booleano.

Na sua primeira condição por exemplo:

```
if(valor>1&&9) {...
```

Se quer comparar se um `valor` esteja entre 1 e 10 deve ser feita assim:

```
if(valor > 1 && valor < 10) {...
```

Pois o operador lógico de conjunção [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) irá:

- Testar a primeiro a sentença `valor > 1`...

  - ...caso o valor dessa sentença seja `true` ele segue para o próximo teste...
  - ...caso o valor dessa sentença seja `false` ele interrompe o teste e retorna false.
- Testa a sentença `valor < 10`..

  - ...caso o valor dessa sentença seja `true` retorna `true`.
  - ...caso o valor dessa sentença seja `false` retorna `false`.

Ou simplesmente o operador de conjunção `&&` testa duas sentença booleanas e retorna true apenas se ambas as sentenças são verdadeiras.

Um adendo com três formas de fazer essas comparações:

Com a declaração [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

```js
do {
  var n = parseInt(window.prompt("Digite um número:"));
} while (isNaN(n));

if (n < 0){
  alert("Negativos não valem!");
} else if (n == 0) {
  alert("Zero!");
} else if (n < 10){
  alert("Muito pouco!");
} else if (n < 15){
  alert("Bom!");
} else if (n < 20){
  alert("Muito bom!");
} else {
  alert("Passou...");
}
```

Com a declaração [switch/case](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```js
do {
  var n = parseInt(window.prompt("Digite um número:"));
} while (isNaN(n));

switch (true) {
  case n < 0:
    alert("Negativos não valem!")
    break;
  case n == 0:
    alert("Zero!")
    break;
  case n < 10:
    alert("Muito pouco!")
    break;
  case n < 15:
    alert("Bom!")
    break;
  case n < 20:
    alert("Muito bom!")
    break;
  default:
    alert("Passou......")
}
```

Com o [operador ternário condicional](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```js
do {
  var n = parseInt(window.prompt("Digite um número:"));
} while (isNaN(n));

alert(
  (n < 0)  ? "Negativos não valem!" :
  (n == 0) ? "Zero" :
  (n < 10) ? "Muito pouco!" :
  (n < 15) ? "Bom!" :
  (n < 20) ? "Muito bom!" :
  "Passou......"
);
```